# Removing block of code with regex not enough 's

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to remove the following part of my code:

```
<!-- 
NewPP limit report
Preprocessor node count: 1/300000
Post‐expand include size: 0/2097152 bytes
Template argument size: 0/2097152 bytes
Expensive parser function count: 0/100
-->

<!-- Saved in parser cache with key creepypasta:pcache:idhash:29041-0!*!*!*!*!2!* -->
```

I have tried the following:

```
body = Regex.Replace(body, @"(<!-- (.*?) -->", "");
```

But I am getting an error:

> parsing not enough 's. regex

Hoe can I use regex to remove the block of code above?

The following code it returned for regex from this url http://creepypasta.wikia.com/wiki/She_Was_Asking_for_It

[image]

Comment: What **exactly** will be returned?

Comment: Sorry, updated my OP.

Comment: No, not a screen shot, what will be removed from the example you provided and the processed *example* text. Not the original source.

Comment: The `.` does not match a newline by default. `RegexOptions.Singleline` enables the `.` to match a newline. And the first `(` just needs removing.

Answer (score 0):

`@"(<!-- (.*?) -->"` is missing a `)`. Try `@"(<!-- (.*?) -->)"`

That answers the failure, but your pattern is circumspect. I would use

`(?<=<!--).+?(?=-->)`

Which has a look behind for `<!--` and a look ahead for `-->`. Also set it to `Multiline` to span lines.

Comment: As an addition to this answer, to the OP I'd recommend using an online tool like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) to prototype regular expression patterns. It will help point out these kinds of simple typos.

Comment: Still not removing the code above :(

Comment: @dontmindmeyo It would also help make sure that your pattern is working properly. If you look at [this application of your pattern](https://regex101.com/r/GNLqnL/1/), the text you provided wouldn't match as I think you intended due to the spaces you included in your pattern.

Comment: @dontmindmeyo updated for my pattern to use. Your question wasn't directly asking for a result, just how to fix the error.